# React Native adb devices not showing up

Tags: android, react-native

I've been working with React Native for about the last week on my mac. After the initial setup which was a pretty huge pain in the ass I've had no issues building my app. Of course, today all builds decide to fail and I get the following message

[image]

I run `adb devices` and it looks like my device has disappeared?

[image]

Debugging, etc is enabled in my settings and I've setup the android environment obviously because I've been developing like this for about the last week.

I vaguely remember using the linux setup to get it working initially

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.21/docs/getting-started-on-linux.html

But now my device isn't even showing up when I run `lsusb`

[image]

I've also tried different USB cables and different ports but still doesn't show up.

Any thoughts what this could be? Thanks

Comment: Have you switched on debug mode on your prone?

Comment: Yeah. Shutting off the phone and rebooting it worked.